# Dynamically move animation on left or right android

Tags: java, javascript, android, xml, layout

Hi i am new in android animation i have image of octopus that moves in layout by XML animation
and i have two flags images of different countries one flag is right on side and one is left on side now i want to move octopus automatically on one side of flag and the movement every
time will be different mean some time movement will be on left side and some time movement on 
right side now how can i do that anyone can give good idea. 
Below is my code ............. XML code for animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

<!-- Use startOffset to give delay between animations -->


<!-- Move -->
<translate
    android:duration="2500"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:startOffset="300"
    android:toXDelta="25%p" />
<translate
    android:duration="2500"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:startOffset="2800"
    android:toYDelta="50%p" />
<translate
    android:duration="2500"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:startOffset="5300"
    android:toXDelta="-25%p" />
<translate
    android:duration="2500"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:startOffset="7800"
    android:toYDelta="-50%p" />

<!-- Rotate 360 degrees -->
<rotate
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="25%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="10300"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toDegrees="180" />

</set>
```

here is java code to access that file

```
Animation fadein_anim;
ImageView animimagej, imageView;// imageView Button and animimagej is octopus image 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
animimagej = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animimage);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
fadein_anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.animator.sequence);
    fadein_anim.setAnimationListener(this);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            animimagej.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            animimagej.startAnimation(fadein_anim);

        }
    });
}
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
 }
```

Comment: Try waiting for your question to be answered properly, instead of adding irrelevant tags to get more views.

Comment: i edit it please check it now sir

Comment: try this it ll help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465568/move-imageview-after-animation-update-position/23467534#23467534

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define object of random Class and generate random number with the help of this object just like below

```
Random a = new Random();
    int b = a.nextInt(5 - 1) + 1;<-------------- generating random number
    switch (b) {
    case 1:

        start.youranimationhere()
        break;

    case 2:


        start.youranimation2here()
        break;
        break;
    case 3:
          //do your job for all case that you declare variable b above
```