# Move imageview after animation (update position)

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-animation

I am trying to to do a translate animation on an image view from the bottom to the middle of the screen. Upon finish of the animation, I want the image view to stay there.  I dont want the setFillAfter(true) because I want the actual position of the imageview to be updated.

I do it currently by having 2 image view (one at the start of animation and one at the end) and I play with the setVisibility to achieve this. Is this the correct way to do things? Here is the code I used:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivStart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/typer_step_1"
    android:gravity="center"
     />



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivMiddle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/typer_step_1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="invisible"
     />    








     TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(0, mDestLoc1[0]-mSrcLoc1[0], 0, mDestLoc1[1]-mSrcLoc1[1]);                   
translate.setDuration(2000);
translate.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        ivMiddle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                        ivStart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)


    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

});

ivStart.startAnimation(translate);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android translate animation - permanently move View to new position using AnimationListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016674/android-translate-animation-permanently-move-view-to-new-position-using-animat)

Comment: in your xml layout, you should instead place the ImageView you're animating on the position you want it to go, before the animation. On starting the animation, translate it such that it looks like it's coming from where you want it to come from.

Comment: @JosephusVillarey hmmm , good suggetion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you must set new `LayoutParams` for your View which is animating. When animation finishes, in your `onAnimationEnd` part, set new position of your `View`.

```
     TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(0, mDestLoc1[0]-mSrcLoc1[0], 0, mDestLoc1[1]-mSrcLoc1[1]);                   
     translate.setDuration(2000);
     translate.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

         @Override
         public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

         @Override
         public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams par = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
             par.topMargin = mDestLoc1[1]-mSrcLoc1[1];
             par.leftMargin = mDestLoc1[0]-mSrcLoc1[0];
             view.setLayoutParams(par);              
         }

         @Override
         public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

     });

     view.startAnimation(translate);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the actual starting position of the image view you can get it at the time of `animationStart` And you can use `setFillAfter(true)`. The `setFillAfter(true)` will update the position after the animation end.

If you need the new position you can use the `setFilter(true)`. If you are not ready to use `setFillAfter(true)` (if you need the older position), then you have done the right thing by having two Image Views. But its better to get the position in `animationStart` and use `setFillAfter(true)`.

Comment: Please read my question. I said specifically I dont want to use it because it does not change the position, it just changes "the cosmatic location"... or you are missing my point

Comment: You can follow this http://graphics-geek.blogspot.in/2011/08/mysterious-behavior-of-fillbefore.html
 link to get the flags fillAfter, fillBefore and fillEnabled. Setting all the three flags to true will be working in your case I assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Snake use my code this ll help you,

```
//Call this in your onCreate

 private void StartAnimationsDtoU() 
{
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alphadtou);
    anim.reset();
    RelativeLayout l=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
    l.clearAnimation();
    l.startAnimation(anim);
    anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
    anim.reset();
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.earth);
    iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    iv.clearAnimation();
    iv.startAnimation(anim);

}
```

This is your linear layout with an image which ll move from down to middle of the screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/lin_lay">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/earth" />
```

and this ll be your xml file for translation i.e translate.xml ...

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"><translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta="0%"
android:toXDelta="0%"
android:fromYDelta="200%"
android:toYDelta="0%"
android:duration="4000"
android:zAdjustment="top" /></set>
```

and this ll be your down to up alphadtou.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><alpha
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromAlpha="0.0"
android:toAlpha="1.0"
android:duration="1000" />
```

and also override onAttachedToWindow method like this...

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
}
```

Hope this ll help you alot.

Comment: Thank you but I dont see the code that changes the position permanently of image view. This will just translate the image

Answer (score -1):

Add this line before starting the animation
`translate.setFillAfter(true);`

Comment: Please read my question. I said specifically I dont want to use it because it does not change the position, it just changes "the cosmatic location"

Comment: It's about moving the view (with updating the position) when the animation is finished, so if you want to move the view again, to start from the updated position, not the initial one.