# Translation of image from center to top in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Hi I have stuck with the problem of creating a splash screen where the image is placed in center_vertical|center horizontal.how to translater over to center_horizontal|top in android.can any one please guide me how to do it.

Comment: Try this android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"

Comment: @Saravanan:how to translate to it

Comment: add this gravity="center_horizontal" properties to your parent layout which hold your image view.

Comment: Try this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465568/move-imageview-after-animation-update-position/23467534#23467534

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use animations to do this, for more information about animating views, you could refer to [this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidAnimation/article.html) and also [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/)

What you are actually looking for in translating a view from the center to the top of the screen, you could use translation animation using the xml.

1.Create a folder anim in the res folder
2.Add a resource file that describes your translation effect like :

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="50%p" android:fromYDelta="50%p" 
    android:toXDelta="50%p" android:toYDelta="0%p" 
    android:duration="1000" 
    android:fillAfter="true" />
```

You could experiment with the % values.

3.implement this in code like :

```
translateAnim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.translate_anim);
imageView.startAnimation(translateAnim);
```

Hope this much of clue suffices!

P.S: You could experiment with `fillAfter` true or false, so that you could understand their effects better.

Comment: @Ratatouille: I need facebook like splash screen can we achieve it

Comment: Yes using animations you can.

Comment: @Ratatouille:i am translating an image over top but after that image has to be fixed where it stops and login layout has been shown at center_vertical and canter_horizontal

Comment: do this, set the image to default center_horizontal, and top , then when the app starts via code start the animation of the view from the center of the screen and then when the animation stops it will remain at its default location when u set fillAfter to true (that is top), this is how generally the animations work

Comment: @Ratatoulli:but there is a slight deviation when it changes.. can u guide me in this..

Comment: yeah, wait, m uploading the sample on github, you could look at it.. just a moment, [here](https://github.com/hearbeathorror/Animating-View-Translate) it is

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille, please help me on this like in the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62756897/android-smooth-animation-not-coming-fine

Answer (score 0):

This is I think best and easiest approach to achieve animation from center to top:

```
ivSplashCenter.animate()
            .translationY(-((rlContainer.height - (ivSplashCenter.height * 2)) / 2).toFloat())
            .setInterpolator(AccelerateInterpolator()).duration = 1500
```

Here, `ivSplashCenter` is imageview and `rlContainer` is my root view of XML

**NOTE:**

One thing you need to understand here is that I am keeping a space from the top edge of the height of the image by `ivSplashCenter.height * 2`,
If you don't want any padding/space at the top then you can just use `ivSplashCenter.height`